# JMeter: url encoded embedded resources

Tags: jmeter, urlencode

I'm setting up some tests with JMeter, and I've seen that it's throwing out an error where trying to download embedded resources inside a web page, that have a path like the following:

www.mydomain.com/resources?getItem={someID}

The problem is that the characters need to be URL-encoded, so the following URL should follow this pattern:

www.mydomain.com/resources?getItem=%7BsomeID%7D

Now, how could instruct JMeter to replace these characters, when found on URLs from embedded resources in the web page? I've been looking at BeanShell PreProcessors, but I'm not sure how's the best way to handle this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show some example of embedded url ?

Comment: A URL from one of the embedded resources, as I posted in the original question, would be something like: www.mydomain.com/resources?getItem={someID}. So, what I'd like to do, is update the URL before JMeter requests the embedded resource.

Comment: there is really {someID} with the '{' and '}', then you should report a bug to jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58137

Until bug is fixed, your option is to disable embedded download and use :

- [CSS/ JQuery Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) to extract URLs
- Use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate over urls

This will only simulate serial download not parallel one.

**Update 15th july 2015:**

Bug has been fixed yesterday night, you can give nightly build a try:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Read:

```
Installing JMeter runtime
Download the _bin and _lib files
Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.
```

Comment: I see, ok, I'll work with these indications then for the moment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeap, I just downloaded the latest nightly build, and this is working now. This fix was super fast! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What about this built in Jmeter function?

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode

Comment: I saw that function, but, how could I use it within a BeanShell PreProcessor? That is, how do I get the URL that will be requested? How do I return that new updated URL for JMeter to request the embedded resource?